# How to approach an interview after being rejected once

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I want to work with a company very much. I have tried getting through once and have been declined. I asked if I could reapply and they agreed.

In my second attempt with the very same company, should I be open about my first attempt to get through? What should I say/avoid saying?

Comment: See also [What is the purpose of a company asking “Have you interviewed with us before?”](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-company-asking-have-you-interviewed-with-us-before)

Comment: If they're agreeing for you to apply again then they didn't reject you. They simply found someone else who they felt better met the qualifications. There's nothing to say that this time around you won't be that someone to someone else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If they have asked you to another interview, then they did not reject you the first time for any reason that cannot be overcome (Such as perception of incompetence, bad recommendations, failing a drug test or a credit check, having a criminal history, lying). If they felt that the result of the first interview was that your were an unacceptable hire, you would be marked that way in thier system or known to the hiring officials as someone not to consider.

Likely they had mulitple people who could do the job and you were second or third choice or they felt you were a better fit for a different job. It is unlikly that a small company would ask you to interview again if they did not think it was a possibility that they would hire (no guarnatees though, you don't know how good your competition is).

If they asked you back for a different position, you may be in a good place, often when we see someone who we think would be better for another opening we have coming up, we might interview that person before advertising the position to get it filled right awy.

Go in with confidence and do your best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and wishes, HLGEM! They have not asked me per se for the next interview. I was the one who asked if a re-application is possible and they said ok. Yes, I am a little fixed on joining ABC...

Comment: Then still you didn't show anything the first time that precluded being hired ever, so analyze what you needed to improve from the first time, fix any decificiencies, then go in with confidence knowing you will nail it this time.

Answer (score 15):

Don't bring it up yourself.

If asked about it, don't lie - try to structure whatever you say in positive, constructive ways (it was a learning experience and such). Explain what you have done since the last interview that makes you a more suitable candidate this time around.

It is entirely possible that the interview is for a different position at a different department and that your previous interview experience is simply irrelevant.

Comment: yes. I certainly don't plan to bring it up! But the possibility is there that my name is in records there. And, I will be applying for the same position. ABC is not very big...

Comment: @TheSilverBullet - The important thing is to frame it in positive terms (what you learned from it and what you have done that makes you more suitable now).

Comment: Yes! That is a good place to start! I am right now working on that part! Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You should tell the company that you have applied to them before. They will want to know - either it will not matter or they will know what the other team thought having a view of the other team's skills and knowledge. If you do not tell them then they do not have the option of doing the latter and will feel that you are wasting their time or hiding something.

In other words not telling them only gives a possibility of lowering the companies view of you whilst telling them has no real downside and if you didn't fail the first time for bad reasons it could benefit you.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working for a company where I got rejected the first time round. I saw an advert in my local job website that described the exact job I went for previously and I told the recruiter that I had applied previously and I personally feel that improved my chances of getting the job. It is a chance for you to let the company know that you have developed yourself and improved your skills so that you can be a part of their team.

I imagine they will most likely not remember you, depending on how long ago you first tried, but I cannot see it hurting your chances to let them know that you applied previously. Just remember to focus on how much yo have improved since you last spoke to them.