# Should I tell a company that I got rejected by you before?

Tags: interviewing, ethics

I checked [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-company-asking-have-you-interviewed-with-us-before) topic before asking this question. To me this is more of an ethical question.
Last year I applied for a job and I couldn't get it due to lack of experience.

In the company's rejection email they told me to study more and apply again if you want (it was an auto email I guess but it said something like what I mentioned). I did so, I studied very hard for the past year and I applied for the job one more time.

Currently I passed 3 stage of hiring process and I'm going for the last one. Till now they didn't mention that I've interviewed here and they didn't question me about it either (I think they don't keep track of their candidates). I didn't mention it too.

Now I'm a bit worry about it, should I tell them about the last time? I believe that I improved a lot and I don't want them to judge me by last interview results in other hand I don't want risk loosing this opportunity due to lack of honesty.

I should also mention that this time I applied for another branch in another city, I mean same company, different branch. The company located in Netherlands.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not relevant. The hiring manager must consider you and what you have to offer as you are today.

Once you're hired it is just a good story. But until you sign the contract, let them take the initiative on it.

Don't hide it. If you're asked, you present it assertively and as a positive ("Yes I did, and I took your feedback and worked to improve.").

Edit, OP requested clarification: If you have a conversation about personal growth with colleagues, it is a relevant and nice story to share. But it does not reflect on your performance in any way, and so you should not feel obliged to share it. It is simply part of your personal journey.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you said *"But until you sign the contract, let them take the initiative on it."* So you think I should mention it after I signed the contract? If you meant this, can you please clarify why? If I shouldn't mention it now, I don't see why should I mention it later.

Comment: @SomeGuy from my experience, this might not be a good idea to provide - without anyone asking - any feedback on previous bad experience of any sorts with the company you're currently working for.
If anyone brings it up in a conversation - don't deny it, but don't start a conversation about it, you might not expect what people and/or coworkers would take out of it.
If you feel it's hard for you to contain this "secret", I suppose that after a few months of employment there you could talk freely about it, considering everyone knows you by now and you know them well enough...

Comment: @ShayLivyatan Thanks, I see your point. I think it's better stay as a "secret" after all.

Comment: @SomeGuy At some point you may find yourself talking about past hiring experiences with your colleagues. And then the story is an interesting bit of personal background that you can be proud of. If someone (incorrectly, imo) perceives it as a negative, you have nothing to lose. During the interview phase you do have something to lose.

Comment: @SambalMinion I see, you are correct. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any ethical reason why you'd be obliged to mention it. I wouldn't bring it up unless it comes up naturally in the interview.

You weren't banned from reapplying, your last application was just unsuccessful. You also can't be sure how close you were to getting the position last time - the fact that they took the time to notify you and suggest a way to improve could be a sign that you were actually one of their top picks. Many companies will just cut off contact if they choose not to proceed with the hiring process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't know why but every time I apply for a job I get kinda paranoid and think that every move by employee is something to test me. In this case I think I should go with your advice.